# Simple PHP for changing page?

Tags: php, html

On my website I have a gallery page. On it I would like a file to be included, and then on a click of a button, I want the next story to load. I know how to use php to include a file with a certain filename by using variables. But how do I integrate a button? Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you talking about pagination?

Comment: You want to add an HTML button? `<button>`?

Comment: You'll place an `include injection` into your site for sure and will be hacked immediately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create  and style it to be like a button..but for grabbing more content from files it would be better to use ajax.

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/5-ways-to-make-ajax-calls-with-jquery/